# Is there a way to move back to stable version of Azure Logic Apps Actions?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I was about to do a stage deployment of my Logic App. Then I found all the Blob actions are in V2 Preview version in the designer view. I did not see any options to use the previous version which I had tested and ensured the functionality is working fine. In order to switch to that version, I had to go to the editor and get the code from my other logic app! I am wondering is there a better way of doing this? It is easy to use the designer to chose actions and triggers than copy paste from previous code!

Answer (score 0):

In Logic App menu under **Development Tools**, select **Versions**

[image]

Select the specific **Version** which you need to use from the list. It will redirect to **History version** page, here we can see the previous version's details in read-only mode. In History version page we have a Designer, Code view & Promote mode.

[image]

In a code view tab we can view the version changes

[image]

In promote tab, we can find and select a version of logic app design flow which need to promoted.

[image]

Select Promote tab, it will redirect to **Logic Apps Designer** page, you can edit the version that you're promoting as needed. You can edit in both **Designer** and **Code view** modes and also update **Parameters**, **Templates**, and **Connectors in a selected version**.
[image]

Comment: I believe is useful when you want to go back to previous version of the logic app code. What I am looking for was to use the previous version of the API. I don't want to use the V2 preview version. But wanted to use the stable previous version of the API.